# HTML file as a js or css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is a stupid question.

But just out of curiosity, is there a way to post an html file(a .html file) as a js/css file (renamed as .js or .css) with the type header as either HTML or js/css and get the data at the browser end in normal html format? I mean the browser reading it as an html itself and display it as any other html page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What matters for the browser when displaying a resource is the Content-Type HTTP header. As long as this header is set by the web server to `text/html`, the extension doesn't really matter. The resource will be interpreted as HTML. So you could configure the web server to serve .js file with a `text/html` Content-Type and it will work.

The file doesn't even need to exist on the server. That's why I prefer to talk about resources instead of files. You could use a server side language and configure it to respond to some virtual address (with the `.js` extension) and serving HTML content with the `text/html` Content-Type header.

Comment: Yes, the Content-Type is all that matters.

Comment: Example: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/odd/hello.js (Has been done using `AddType text/html;charset=utf-8 JS` in the `.htaccess` file of the directory, when using an Apache server.)

Comment: IE is known to violate Internet protocols regarding content type in some situations, overriding the `Content-Type` header when it thinks it knows better. But this probably won’t matter here; it mostly makes IE treat a document as text/html on the basis of the actual contents.